# Powershell script to compare processes from text file

Tags: powershell

I need to do the following:

- Get a list of all the current processes on the system and save them to a text file called “before.txt”
- Launch a new browser window (Chrome, Edge, Firefox – your choice)
- Get a new list of all the current processes on the system and save them to a text file called “after.txt”
- Using the compare-object cmdlet in PowerShell, find the new process ID for the browser you just opened
- Once the process ID has been identified, kill the process using that process ID

I'm having difficulty completing the last task of killing the identified process from the text file. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

########################## Current Script#########################

```
Get-Process | select-object -Expand Name > before.txt
Invoke-Item "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
Start-Sleep -s 3
Get-Process | select-object -Expand Name > after.txt
Compare-Object (get-content before.txt) (Get-Content after.txt) > final.text
$list = Get-Content final.text; Get-Process $list | kill -force -Raw
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple fix to your code is to change the `compare-object` line.  Try running that line without the redirect and you'll see it's not a simple list of names.  Try changing that line in your script to the following:

```
Compare-Object (get-content before.txt) (Get-Content after.txt) | select -ExpandProperty InputObject > final.text
```

However, in PowerShell you don't need to use all these temporary files.  You can have arrays of items.  A more PowerShell answer would be:

```
$before = Get-Process
Invoke-Item ...
$after = Get-Process
$list = Compare-Object $before $after
$list |% { stop-process $_.InputObject.id }
```

Comment: when I run the script without the redirect, it's producing the final.txt file with the iexplorer process name but how do I get the script to use the results from that file, find the name of the process and kill it?

Comment: as per my answer - use a `select -ExpandProperty` in your pipline to just get a list of names then read that in again as you did originally.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you! Do you offer tutoring? I am desperately needing help in this powershell class. Anyways, thank you again!

Comment: Great stuff, happy to help.  Please consider marking the answer as accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers